# VB.Net Update an existing Listview from a DataGridView on another Form

Tags: vb.net, listview, datagridview

So I have a Form loaded with 2 ListViews. The first, lv1 is randomly populated with ticket numbers. The second, lv2 has a button that launches a datagridview form where I enter manual ticket numbers into and a bunch of error checking is done in each cell when a ticket is entered into it.

How do I get the datagridview to update to the listview? Everything I try, nothing happens. I created a form where this is possible when the datagridview and listviews are all on the same form and it works fine. However, I'd like it to work across forms.

[image]

```
  Private Sub cmdDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDone.Click
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        FrmCycleCount.LvwYardTickets.Items.Clear()

        For i As Integer = 0 To Dgv.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim item As ListViewItem
              Dim arr(3) As String

            arr(0) = Dgv.Item(0, i).Value.ToString()
            arr(1) = gCycleYCnt
            arr(2) = "Yes"

            item = New ListViewItem(arr)
            FrmCycleCount.LvwYardTickets.Items.Add(item)
        Next
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use DataBindings. -- It's not clear at all what is the relation between the two ListView Controls and the DataGridView, what the *second* ListView contains and what ListView needs to be updated. It's also not clear why you need another Form to edit these values.

Comment: Adding images to the post may be useful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. There is no relationship between the 2 listviews. Its an inventory control feature. I work for a lumber company and the first listview is populated with 10 random tickets from our database that a user uses to go find the physical inventory in the yard. The second listview is to display 10 random tickets that same user pulls from the yard. We want them to enter those yard tickets into the datagridview which does error and format checking as they are entering each ticket in. Then when they are done, I want that datgridview to update to the listview.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/KKvhbQa.png

Comment: When should the data be updated from the DataGridView to the ListView? When a button is pressed?

Comment: @user9938 Yes. when the Done/cmdDone button is pressed on the datagridview form

Comment: Should data be preserved in the ListView or overwritten?

Comment: Preserved in the first listview (the one on the left) and then the second one (one on the right) gets populated from the dgv.

Comment: Is FrmCycleCount the actual instance of the 1st form with the listviews or is that the Type?  Are you passing a reference of your 1st form into the 2nd form anywhere?

Comment: frmCycleCount is instantiated from the frmMain. frmEnterTickets (the DGV form) is instantiated from frmCycleCount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass data from a Form one can use an event. This works whether the form was opened using [Show()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/show-method) or [ShowDiaglog()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=net-5.0). If you're using ShowDialog, then there's another way of passing the data back, but since you didn't state that you intended to use ShowDialog, I won't discuss that here-I'll be using `Show()`.

Given that you have two forms:

- Form1
- Form2

where there is a button on Form1 (btnAdd), when clicked opens Form2.

[image]

First, create a class (name: TicketInfo.vb) for the data.

**TicketInfo.vb**

```
Public Class TicketInfo
    Private _found As String = String.Empty
    Private _pass As String = String.Empty
    Private _ticketNo As String = String.Empty

    Public Property Found As String
        Get
            Return _found
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _found = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Pass As String
        Get
            Return _pass
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _pass = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TicketNo As String
        Get
            Return _ticketNo
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ticketNo = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Sub New(ticketNo As String, pass As String)
        Me.TicketNo = ticketNo
        Me.Pass = pass
        Me.Found = Found
    End Sub

    Sub New(ticketNo As String, pass As String, found As String)
        Me.TicketNo = ticketNo
        Me.Pass = pass
        Me.Found = found
    End Sub

End Class
```

Create a form (name: Form2.vb) and add a DataGridView to it.

Add two columns:

1. Ticket#
2. Pass

[image]

Add a `ContextMenuStrip` (from the Toolbox) to Form2. Then type "Delete" where it says "Type Here". Double-click the word "Delete" to create the event handler.

[image]

In order to use an event to pass our data to the other form, we'll create a class and a delegate.

Create a class (name: DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs.vb)

**Note**: I've only defined one property, but we could add additional properties to the class if we wanted to. We'll also put our delegate in this file. However, the delegate is defined outside of the class. Notice that the second parameter for the delegate is the name of the class.

**DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs.vb**

```
Public Delegate Sub DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs)

Public Class DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs

    Public ReadOnly Property Tickets As List(Of TicketInfo)

    Sub New(tickets As List(Of TicketInfo))
        Me.Tickets = tickets
    End Sub

End Class
```

In the Form2 code (Form2.vb) we create an event that can be raised by the code in Form2. Notice that `DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventHandler` is the name of our delegate.

```
Public Event DataGridViewValueUpdated As DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventHandler
```

Notice the naming strategy for the class, delegate, and event. Both the class name and the delegate start with the name of the event.

- **Event**: DataGridViewValueUpdated
- **Delegate**: "DataGridViewValueUpdated" + "EventHandler" = DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventHandler
- **Class**: "DataGridViewValueUpdated" + "EventArgs" = DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs

See [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/) for more information.

We'll use a `List(Of TicketInfo)` to hold our data and pass it back to Form1.

```
Private tickets As List(Of TicketInfo) = New List(Of TicketInfo)
```

When the `Done` button is clicked, we'll get the data from the DataGridView and pass it back to any subscribers by raising the event.

```
 Private Sub btnDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
    'commit
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()

    'set value
    Dim lastRowIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    If DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).IsNewRow Then
        'set value
        lastRowIndex -= 1 'subtract 1
    End If

    'clear existing items
    tickets.Clear()

    For i As Integer = 0 To lastRowIndex
        'get values
        Dim ticketNo As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()
        Dim pass As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()

        'add
        tickets.Add(New TicketInfo(ticketNo, pass))
    Next

    'raise event (send data to subscribers)
    RaiseEvent DataGridViewValueUpdated(Me, New DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs(tickets))

    'close
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

In Form1, we'll create an instance of Form2 (name: frm2).

```
Private frm2 As Form2 = Nothing
```

In the `Add` button (btnAdd), Click event handler we'll add code that creates a new instance of Form2 (if necessary), and subscribes to the `DataGridViewValueUpdated` event, as well as the `FormClosed` event. If the form has been minimized, we'll show it again.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    If frm2 Is Nothing Then
        'create new instance
        frm2 = New Form2()

        'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
        AddHandler frm2.DataGridViewValueUpdated, AddressOf Frm2_DataGridViewValueUpdated
        AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Frm2_FormClosed
        frm2.Show()
    Else
        frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        frm2.Activate()
    End If
End Sub
```

Create the event handler code for `DataGridView2ValueUpdated`.

**Frm2_DataGridViewValueUpdated**

```
Private Sub Frm2_DataGridViewValueUpdated(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs)
    'ToDo: add desired code

    'set value
    Dim tickets As List(Of TicketInfo) = e.Tickets

    'clear existing items
    ListView2.Items.Clear()

    For Each ticket As TicketInfo In tickets
        Dim row As String() = {ticket.TicketNo, ticket.Pass, ticket.Found}
        Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)

        'add
        ListView2.Items.Add(lvItem)
    Next

    'set value
    TextBoxLv2TicketCount.Text = ListView2.Items.Count

End Sub
```

Add an event handler for the frm2 `FormClosed` event. When frm2 is closed, we'll remove our event handlers and set the value to Nothing.

```
Private Sub Frm2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    'unsubscribe from events (remove event handlers)
    RemoveHandler frm2.DataGridViewValueUpdated, AddressOf Frm2_DataGridViewValueUpdated
    RemoveHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Frm2_FormClosed

    'dispose
    frm2.Dispose()

    'set value
    frm2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Here's the complete code for "Form1.vb" and "Form2.vb"- the complete code for "DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs.vb" and "TicketInfo.vb" can be found above.

**Form1.vb** (complete code)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private frm2 As Form2 = Nothing

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'set property
        ListView1.View = View.Details
        ListView2.View = View.Details

        'load test data
        LoadTestData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadTestData()
        ListView1.Items.Clear()

        Dim lv1Tickets As New List(Of TicketInfo)

        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B034129", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B043999", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B044745", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B048767", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B050236", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B050960", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B052688", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B054892", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B882313", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B989873", "1", "No"))

        For Each ticket As TicketInfo In lv1Tickets
            Dim row As String() = {ticket.TicketNo, ticket.Pass, ticket.Found}
            Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)

            'add
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvItem)
        Next

        'set value
        TextBoxLv1TicketCount.Text = ListView1.Items.Count
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        If frm2 Is Nothing Then
            'create new instance
            frm2 = New Form2()

            'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
            AddHandler frm2.DataGridViewValueUpdated, AddressOf Frm2_DataGridViewValueUpdated
            AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Frm2_FormClosed
            frm2.Show()
        Else
            frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
            frm2.Activate()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Frm2_DataGridViewValueUpdated(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs)
        'ToDo: add desired code

        'set value
        Dim tickets As List(Of TicketInfo) = e.Tickets

        'clear existing items
        ListView2.Items.Clear()

        For Each ticket As TicketInfo In tickets
            Dim row As String() = {ticket.TicketNo, ticket.Pass, ticket.Found}
            Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)

            'add
            ListView2.Items.Add(lvItem)
        Next

        'set value
        TextBoxLv2TicketCount.Text = ListView2.Items.Count

    End Sub

    Private Sub Frm2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
        'unsubscribe from events (remove event handlers)
        RemoveHandler frm2.DataGridViewValueUpdated, AddressOf Frm2_DataGridViewValueUpdated
        RemoveHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Frm2_FormClosed

        'dispose
        frm2.Dispose()

        'set value
        frm2 = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2.vb** (complete code)

**Note** The code below assumes that you have a `ContextMenuStrip` (name: ContextMenuStrip1) on Form2 that is assigned to the `ContextMenuStrip` property of `DataGridView1`.

```
Public Class Form2

    Public Event DataGridViewValueUpdated As DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventHandler
    Private tickets As List(Of TicketInfo) = New List(Of TicketInfo)

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            'remove row
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
        'commit
        DataGridView1.EndEdit()

        'set value
        Dim lastRowIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        If DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).IsNewRow Then
            'set value
            lastRowIndex -= 1 'subtract 1
        End If

        'clear existing items
        tickets.Clear()

        For i As Integer = 0 To lastRowIndex
            'get values
            Dim ticketNo As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()
            Dim pass As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()

            'add
            tickets.Add(New TicketInfo(ticketNo, pass))
        Next

        'create new instance and set property
        'Dim args As DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs = New DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs(tickets)
        'raise event (send data to subscribers)
        'RaiseEvent DataGridViewValueUpdated(Me, args)

        'raise event (send data to subscribers)
        RaiseEvent DataGridViewValueUpdated(Me, New DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs(tickets))

        'close
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            'remove row
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

---

**Alternate Option**:

I'll show an alternate way of using an event and delegate without using a class-the code below eliminates the need for  "DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventArgs.vb". I won't include all the code, but rather highlight the changes/differences.

Form2.vb (alternate option):

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Delegate Sub DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As List(Of TicketInfo))
    Public Event DataGridViewValueUpdated As DataGridViewValueUpdatedEventHandler
    Private tickets As List(Of TicketInfo) = New List(Of TicketInfo)
                       ...
    Private Sub btnDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
                       ...
        RaiseEvent DataGridViewValueUpdated(Me, tickets)
                       ...
    End Sub
                       ...
End Class
```

Form1.vb (alternate option):

```
Public Class Form1
                   ...
    Private Sub Frm2_DataGridViewValueUpdated(sender As Object, e As List(Of TicketInfo))
    
        Dim tickets As List(Of TicketInfo) = e
                   ...
    End Sub
                   ...
End Class
```

Comment: Wow man! Thanks for all that! I will take a try at it tomorrow and let you know how I fared, but it looks like you have it doing exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to use [Show()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/show-method) - without using an event to pass the data. I also show how to use [ShowDialog()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8).

Given that you have two forms:

- Form1
- Form2

where there is a button on Form1 (btnAdd), when clicked opens Form2.

[image]

First, create a class (name: TicketInfo.vb) for the data.

**TicketInfo.vb**

```
Public Class TicketInfo
    Private _found As String = String.Empty
    Private _pass As String = String.Empty
    Private _ticketNo As String = String.Empty

    Public Property Found As String
        Get
            Return _found
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _found = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Pass As String
        Get
            Return _pass
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _pass = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TicketNo As String
        Get
            Return _ticketNo
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ticketNo = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Sub New(ticketNo As String, pass As String)
        Me.TicketNo = ticketNo
        Me.Pass = pass
        Me.Found = Found
    End Sub

    Sub New(ticketNo As String, pass As String, found As String)
        Me.TicketNo = ticketNo
        Me.Pass = pass
        Me.Found = found
    End Sub
End Class
```

Create a form (name: Form2.vb) and add a DataGridView to it.

Add two columns:

1. Ticket#
2. Pass

[image]

Add a ContextMenuStrip (from the Toolbox) to Form2. Then type "Delete" where it says "Type Here". Double-click the word "Delete" to create the event handler.

[image]

We'll use a List(Of TicketInfo) to hold our data and pass it back to Form1-we'll use a ReadOnly Property.

```
Public ReadOnly Property Tickets As List(Of TicketInfo) = New List(Of TicketInfo)
```

**Note**: At this point one needs to decide whether one wants to use `Show` or `ShowDialog`. If you wan to allow the user to make changes to Form1, while Form2 is open, use `Show()`. If you don't want the user to make changes to Form1, while Form2 is open, use `ShowDialog()`.

---

**Option 1 - Show()**

In Form2, when the Done button is clicked, we'll get the data from the DataGridView, add it the the List, and close the form.

```
Private Sub btnDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
    'commit
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()

    'set value
    Dim lastRowIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    If DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).IsNewRow Then
        'set value
        lastRowIndex -= 1 'subtract 1
    End If

    'clear existing items
    Tickets.Clear()

    For i As Integer = 0 To lastRowIndex
        'get values
        Dim ticketNo As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()
        Dim pass As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()

        'add
        Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo(ticketNo, pass))
    Next

    'close
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

In Form1, we'll create an instance of Form2 (name: frm2).

```
Private frm2 As Form2 = Nothing
```

In the Add button (btnAdd), Click event handler we'll add code that creates a new instance of Form2 (if necessary), and subscribes to the FormClosed event. If the form has been minimized, we'll show it again.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    If frm2 Is Nothing Then
        'create new instance
        frm2 = New Form2()

        'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
        AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Frm2_FormClosed

        'show form
        frm2.Show()
    Else
        frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        frm2.Activate()
    End If
End Sub
```

Create the event handler code for the frm2 `FormClosed` event. When frm2 is closed, we'll remove the event handler and set the value of frm2 to Nothing.

```
Private Sub Frm2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)

    'ToDo: add desired code

    'clear existing items
    ListView2.Items.Clear()

    For Each ticket As TicketInfo In frm2.Tickets
        Dim row As String() = {ticket.TicketNo, ticket.Pass, ticket.Found}
        Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)

        'add
        ListView2.Items.Add(lvItem)
    Next

    'set value
    TextBoxLv2TicketCount.Text = ListView2.Items.Count

    'dispose
    frm2.Dispose()

    'set value
    frm2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here's the complete code for "Form1.vb" and "Form2.vb"- the complete code for "TicketInfo.vb" can be found above.

**Form1.vb** (option 1 - complete code)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private frm2 As Form2 = Nothing

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'set property
        ListView1.View = View.Details
        ListView2.View = View.Details

        'load test data
        LoadTestData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadTestData()
        ListView1.Items.Clear()

        Dim lv1Tickets As New List(Of TicketInfo)

        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B034129", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B043999", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B044745", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B048767", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B050236", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B050960", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B052688", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B054892", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B882313", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B989873", "1", "No"))

        For Each ticket As TicketInfo In lv1Tickets
            Dim row As String() = {ticket.TicketNo, ticket.Pass, ticket.Found}
            Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)

            'add
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvItem)
        Next

        'set value
        TextBoxLv1TicketCount.Text = ListView1.Items.Count
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        If frm2 Is Nothing Then
            'create new instance
            frm2 = New Form2()

            'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
            AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Frm2_FormClosed

            'show form
            frm2.Show()
        Else
            frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
            frm2.Activate()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Frm2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)

        'ToDo: add desired code

        'clear existing items
        ListView2.Items.Clear()

        For Each ticket As TicketInfo In frm2.Tickets
            Dim row As String() = {ticket.TicketNo, ticket.Pass, ticket.Found}
            Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)

            'add
            ListView2.Items.Add(lvItem)
        Next

        'set value
        TextBoxLv2TicketCount.Text = ListView2.Items.Count

        'dispose
        frm2.Dispose()

        'set value
        frm2 = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2.vb** (option 1 - complete code)

Note The code below assumes that you have a ContextMenuStrip (name: ContextMenuStrip1) on Form2 that is assigned to the ContextMenuStrip property of DataGridView1.

```
Public Class Form2
    Public ReadOnly Property Tickets As List(Of TicketInfo) = New List(Of TicketInfo)

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            'remove row
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
        'commit
        DataGridView1.EndEdit()

        'set value
        Dim lastRowIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        If DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).IsNewRow Then
            'set value
            lastRowIndex -= 1 'subtract 1
        End If

        'clear existing items
        Tickets.Clear()

        For i As Integer = 0 To lastRowIndex
            'get values
            Dim ticketNo As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()
            Dim pass As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()

            'add
            Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo(ticketNo, pass))
        Next

        'close
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            'remove row
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

---

**Option 2 - ShowDialog()**

In Form2, when the Done button is clicked, we'll get the data from the DataGridView, add it the the List, set the value for DialogResult, and close the form. When using `ShowDialog()`, `btnAdd_Click` doesn't return until Form2 is closed. This means that nothing can be done on Form1, while Form2 is open. When using the code below, if Form2 is minimized, clicking anywhere on Form1, will show Form2 again.

```
Private Sub btnDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
    'commit
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()

    'set value
    Dim lastRowIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    If DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).IsNewRow Then
        'set value
        lastRowIndex -= 1 'subtract 1
    End If

    'clear existing items
    Tickets.Clear()

    For i As Integer = 0 To lastRowIndex
        'get values
        Dim ticketNo As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()
        Dim pass As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()

        'add
        Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo(ticketNo, pass))
    Next

    'set value
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK

    'close
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

In Form1, we'll create an instance of Form2 (name: frm2).

```
Private frm2 As Form2 = Nothing
```

In the Add button (btnAdd), Click event handler we'll add code that creates a new instance of Form2, and subscribes to the Activated event. If the form has been minimized, we'll show it again.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    'create new instance
    frm2 = New Form2()

    'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
    AddHandler frm2.Activated, AddressOf Frm2_Activated

    If frm2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        'clear existing items
        ListView2.Items.Clear()

        For Each ticket As TicketInfo In frm2.Tickets
            Dim row As String() = {ticket.TicketNo, ticket.Pass, ticket.Found}
            Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)

            'add
            ListView2.Items.Add(lvItem)
        Next

        'set value
        TextBoxLv2TicketCount.Text = ListView2.Items.Count
    End If

    'unsubscribe from events (remove event handlers)
    RemoveHandler frm2.Activated, AddressOf Frm2_Activated

    frm2.Dispose()
    frm2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Create the event handler code for the frm2 Activated event. When using ShowDialog() and Form2 is open (even if minimized), clicking on Form1 will activate Form2.

```
Private Sub Frm2_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'restore window
    frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
End Sub
```

Here's the complete code for "Form1.vb" and "Form2.vb"- the complete code for "TicketInfo.vb" can be found above.

**Form1.vb** (option 2 - complete code)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private frm2 As Form2 = Nothing
    Private frm2DialogResult As DialogResult = DialogResult.None

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'set property
        ListView1.View = View.Details
        ListView2.View = View.Details

        'load test data
        LoadTestData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadTestData()
        ListView1.Items.Clear()

        Dim lv1Tickets As New List(Of TicketInfo)

        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B034129", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B043999", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B044745", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B048767", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B050236", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B050960", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B052688", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B054892", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B882313", "1", "No"))
        lv1Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo("B989873", "1", "No"))

        For Each ticket As TicketInfo In lv1Tickets
            Dim row As String() = {ticket.TicketNo, ticket.Pass, ticket.Found}
            Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)

            'add
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvItem)
        Next

        'set value
        TextBoxLv1TicketCount.Text = ListView1.Items.Count
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        'create new instance
        frm2 = New Form2()

        'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
        AddHandler frm2.Activated, AddressOf Frm2_Activated

        If frm2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            'clear existing items
            ListView2.Items.Clear()

            For Each ticket As TicketInfo In frm2.Tickets
                Dim row As String() = {ticket.TicketNo, ticket.Pass, ticket.Found}
                Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)

                'add
                ListView2.Items.Add(lvItem)
            Next

            'set value
            TextBoxLv2TicketCount.Text = ListView2.Items.Count
        End If

        'unsubscribe from events (remove event handlers)
        RemoveHandler frm2.Activated, AddressOf Frm2_Activated

        frm2.Dispose()
        frm2 = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Frm2_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'restore window
        frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2.vb** (option 2 - complete code)

```
Public Class Form2
    Public ReadOnly Property Tickets As List(Of TicketInfo) = New List(Of TicketInfo)

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            'remove row
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
        'commit
        DataGridView1.EndEdit()

        'set value
        Dim lastRowIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        If DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).IsNewRow Then
            'set value
            lastRowIndex -= 1 'subtract 1
        End If

        'clear existing items
        Tickets.Clear()

        For i As Integer = 0 To lastRowIndex
            'get values
            Dim ticketNo As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()
            Dim pass As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).EditedFormattedValue.ToString()

            'add
            Tickets.Add(New TicketInfo(ticketNo, pass))
        Next

        'set value
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK

        'close
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            'remove row
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]